# Twilio - incoming call request - Invalid Content-Type error

Tags: php

I send an incoming Twilio phone call request to my simple endpoint.

```
use Twilio\Twiml; // All documentation says TwiML but that errors
$response = new Twiml;
$response->say(
    "Thank you for calling", 
    array("voice" => "alice")
    );
echo $response;
```

Here is what echoed:

```
<<
? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "UTF-8" ? >
    <
    Response > < Say voice = "alice" > Thank you
for calling < /Say>< /Response >
    null
```

My guess is it is the two < (less than) symbol which seems to be a single character and I couldn't figure out how to change it to a single <.

The Twilio console debugger shows a Content-type error 12300.

Calling my Twilio number plays a recording "An application error has occurred."

If anyone can help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _“Here is what echoed”_ - in that actual terrible formatting? (Or did you mess with this, because you had trouble formatting the code properly?) I think it is rather unlikely that the library produces these double `<` - much more likely that’s coming from your surrounding code somehow.

Comment: follow this link and read carefully maybe you are missing something.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-php

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it to work.  It only took me all day.

Added: header("content-type: text/xml"); // apparently Twilio Library doesn't declare content type

Wordpress issue adding leading whitespace/line breaks: https://www.asce4s.me/fix-wordpress-sitemap-error/

using die (instead of return) so that no value is returned.

Comment: I added: "$response = substr($response, 1);" which removed both <, which is why i concluded it was a single character?

Comment: I added: header("content-type: text/xml"); which puts me step further. But Twilio Debugger now shows  The processing instruction target matching \"[xX][mM][lL]\" is not allowed.  It puts two line breaks above document type declaration.